# How to save text file with UTF-8 encoding in java?

Tags: java, file-io, encoding, utf-8

I am facing a problem in saving a text file in UTF-8 format using java. When i click on save as for the generated text file, it gives ANSI as text format but not as UTF-8. Below is the code i am writing while creating the file:

```
    String excelFile="";

    excelFile = getFullFilePath(fileName);
    File file = new File(excelFile + fileName,"UTF-8");
    File output = new File(excelFile,"UTF-8");

    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, content, "UTF-8");
```

While creating the text file, I am using UTF-8 encoding, but the file still shows the encoding as ANSI while saving.
Kindly help.

Comment: refer this URL
http://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/io/how-to-read-write-utf-8-encoded-data-in-java/

Comment: Why do you assume that the second parameter in the `File` constructor is for encoding? Did you read [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))?

Comment: What is encoding of original file? Also your code not correct. Second parameter of constructor File is "child", not "encoding". And show please, how do you initialize content variable.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using File, create a FileOutputStream. 
Try this.

```
Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
    new FileOutputStream("outfilename"), "UTF-8"));
try {
    out.write(aString);
} finally {
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have tried this, but still it gives ANSI format while saving.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem very similar to that and I solved saving the original file with the UTF-8 encoding. In this case, go to the excel file and save it again, or create a new file and copy the content, and make sure that its encoding is UTF-8. This link has a tutorial on how to save an excel file with UTF-8 encoding: https://help.surveygizmo.com/help/encode-an-excel-file-to-utf-8-or-utf-16. At the most your code seems to be correct.